# Automatically create list item occurrences

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I am trying to create a number of list items that have the same information except the date which is automatically filled in with, for example, 1 week between each list item.

Creating a recurrent event in a calendar web part isn't an option because if I do so, the created events would be the same item and not a number of different items.

Do you have an idea on how to solve this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use quick edit.

Prepare the data in excel in advance (drop-down data autofill) and copy and paste it into the list.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's also possible to create a list with the day of the month (like 1 or 31...) and create a query with access, but you still have to manually enter each element that has the same information because it's the same event at the end. Maybe you have to do some web part programming, but isn't it possible to create a recurrent event in a calendar web part that creates DIFFERENT items ?

Comment: By default, recurrent event in a calendar web part can't create different items. 
I haven't thought of a more appropriate OOB method to fulfill your needs.

Comment: Problem is, you'll encounter difficulties when filling more complex column types then text.